# How to use svn commanline to checkout folder names having spaces

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to use svn command line to checkout a directory from my svn trunk.
But this folder name has space in between them. So I am not able to checkout. I am not facing any issues with SVN GUI.

What i am trying in svn --username test--password test co http://svn-internal/repos/trunk/ABC/Monday Morning.

I am getting error like repository does not exist.What is the right way to specify directory names having spaces in command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
svn co "my repo" "local path"
```

Use double quotes for repo url and local path in any svn command, if you need the long path.

Comment: Thanks that helped. I had to use double quotes on entire url like " co http://svn-internal/repos/trunk/ABC/Monday Morning" as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Putting quotations did not help me on a AIX box. I had to use ASCII space character.

Example: I'm trying to checkout "http://server.com/svn/project location"

`svn checkout http://server.com/svn/project%20location`

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp